# iOS App Crashes while releasing a retained property

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uikit, autorelease

I have a question. There may be a very simple solution to this question but I am not able to figure it out yet. If I use a property say `@property(nonatomic, retain)UIView *mainView`.

Now I synthesize it in .m file and release it in the dealloc method as following:

```
- (void)dealloc {
   [mainView release], mainView = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Then in my `viewDidLoad`, I'm allocating it and adding it as the subview of my `self.view` like following:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

  mainView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  .
  .
  .
  [self.view addSubView: mainView];
}
```

Now I understand that at this point my `mainView` would have 3 reference counts (one from alloc, one because it's a retained property, and the third one when I added it to `self.view`), its parent controller would own it too.
Now, my question is if after adding my view to self.view, I release my mainView using

```
[mainView release];
```

My app crashes when I go back to the previous view as I am sending release to already deallocated object. Now my question is how am I overreleasing my view here. what am I missing because when I use following code it works fine and no crashes occur.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  self.mainView = newView;
  [newView release];
  .
  .
  .
  [self.view addSubView: mainView];
}
```

I know why this second viewDidLoad method works but what I dont know is why first one fails, I am supposed to release my view after adding it to self.view. Right?

**NOTE: I understand that in the first viewDidLoad, I can use autorelease method to release the view that is being assigned to the ivar and it wont crash but the whole point is I am trying to reduce the use of autorelease as much as possible. And I am not using ARC at all**

I would really appreciate the explanation and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your `@property` to retain the `mainView`, you should use it as `self.mainView` and not just `mainView`. If you use the latter alone, it will not retain it. Basically if you call `self.mainView = ...` it is calling a setter method for `mainView` which does a `[mainView retain];` internally. When you are directly assigning it, it wont execute this setter and retain will not be executed.

You should try it like this,

```
self.mainView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.view addSubView:self.mainView];
```

or as shown in your question.

```
UIView *newView = [UIView alloc] init];
self.mainView = newView;
[newView release];
[self.view addSubView:self.mainView];
```

You can also try using ARC for your project. Your code will look like this in ARC,

```
self.mainView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubView:self.mainView];
```

Check [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW2) for more details.

Comment: thanks a lot so the only way to avoid autorelease while not using ARC is the way I did it in my second viewDidLoad method?

Comment: @VikSingh, Yes, You are correct. That is the way we used to do in non-ARC. In fact we used the autorelease one. If you feel my above explanation is helpful, could you please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

From your question:

> Now i understand that at this point my mainView would have 3 reference
>   counts (one from alloc, one coz its a retained property and the third
>   one when i added it to self.view)

You didn't assign through the property but assigned directly to the instance variable, so there was no retain; only in ARC does assigning to the instance variable retain the value. So, do not perform the manual release.

Answer (score 2):

In your first viewDidLoad method you are not referring to self.mainView only mainView thats why its not retained, in order to retain property work you have to set mainView using self.mainView!